# ActionScript : How to check an even to complete?

Tags: actionscript

I have never worked on action script. need help with listener. I am calling and event DrawManager.ZOOM_TO_SELECTION but need to wait for this event to finish before I call the next function "saveMapImage". Can anyone tell me how to do that with a code example?

```
    public function saveMapImageAndForward(projectLocationWKT:String, projectMapType:String, hasMapImageFromIPaCMap:String, projectName:String):void {
        this.projectLocationWKT = projectLocationWKT;
        this.projectMapType = projectMapType;
        this.hasMapImageFromIPaCMap = hasMapImageFromIPaCMap;
        this.projectName = projectName;

        //GlobalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));

         GlobalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new AppEvent(DrawManager.ZOOM_TO_SELECTION));

        //GlobalDispatcher.removeEventListener

        saveMapImage();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function someFunctionCalledAheadOfTime():void
{
    .
    .
    .
    GlobalDispatcher.addEventListener(DrawManager.ZOOM_TO_SELECTION, saveMapImage);
    .
    .
    .
}

public function saveMapImageAndForward(projectLocationWKT:String, projectMapType:String, hasMapImageFromIPaCMap:String, projectName:String):void {
    this.projectLocationWKT = projectLocationWKT;
    this.projectMapType = projectMapType;
    this.hasMapImageFromIPaCMap = hasMapImageFromIPaCMap;
    this.projectName = projectName;

    //GlobalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));

     GlobalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new AppEvent(DrawManager.ZOOM_TO_SELECTION));

    //GlobalDispatcher.removeEventListener

    //saveMapImage();
}

private function saveMapImage(pEvent:AppEvent):void
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

EDIT: It looks like AppEvent is not a very standard class, and it may be one of your own.  I'm basing this off of the assumptions that AppEvent inherits from Event, and that the one-argument constructor works the same way as in the case of a regular Event.

Comment: another way to do this as using ZoomEvent.ZOOM_END . But if the map is already zoomed in, this event will never fire. You may need to add a timer to redirect to alternate path if your program is listening to the event ZoomEvent.ZOOM_END.
    .